# How to display the result of a column sum from PostgreSQL using JQUERY?

Tags: jquery, ajax, postgresql

I have added the query into the webservice js files, and I have written the AJAX call in my JS file. But I am unsure how to display the result of the sum in my function

Web Service queries:

```
cartTotal = async (res) =>
{       
    let client = GetClient();
    console.log(`Displaying Total`);
    try
    {
        await client.connect();
        
        let query = 'SELECT SUM ("Price") FROM "Basket"';
        let results = await client.query(query);
        
        if(results.rows.length > 0)
            console.log(`Read ${results.rows.length} records`)
        else
            console.log(`Database is empty`);
        
        res.send(results.rows);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(403).send(error);
    }
    finally
    {
        await client.end();
    }   
};
```

```
service.get('/Basket', async (req, res) => {
        await db.cartTotal(req.query.name, res);        
});
```

JS functions:

```
 function displayCartTotal(){
        $.ajax({
            cache:false,
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://localhost:1339/Basket',
            data:'',
            contentType: "appliation/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: showTotal,
            error: (req,status,error)=>console.log("error")
        });
    }

   
    function showTotal()
{
    //Not sure how to display the SUM called
}
```

When I do a console log, it reaches success. I am having trouble displaying the actual result though as I am not sure how to define it?

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax success, can you try to do this below :

```
success: function (response) {
 console.log(response)
},
```

if the response has value, then you can pass it on your `function showTotal()` then you can manipulate whatever data inside that response.

Comment: Ah, its pulling back the whole table row, and not the sum of the one column so there must be something wrong with how I am pulling back the webservice query

Comment: you can manipulate it using jquery or javascript if you only want the sum.